# How to perform wild card search in a vector of strings using cloudant selector query

Tags: wildcard, cloudant

There are different documents consisting of the following structure:

```
 1."dev": {
    "urls": ["https://text.com/00a51073"]
  }

 2. "dev": {
            "urls": ["https://text.com/410578c1","https://text.com/00a51073"]
          }
```

How do I perform a wild card search so that a search for "00a51073" should return both the above documents?

```
{
   "selector": {
      "$and": [
         {
            "$or": [
               {
                  "dev": {
                     "urls": {
                        "$regex": ".*00a51073"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a vanilla map-reduce view instead? Just use the last bit of each url as the key, and you can retrieve all docs as a range query. A map might look like

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc && doc.dev && doc.dev.urls) {
        doc.dev.urls.forEach(function(url) {
            var data = url.split("/");
            emit(data[data.len-1], 1);
        });
    }
}
```

and then you can query it something like

```
curl 'https://...cloudant.com/DB/_design/DD/_view/by_url?startkey="00a51073"&endkey="00a51073."&include_docs=true'
```